# Adding content control throws an exception dynamically

Tags: c#-4.0, vsto, add-in, office-interop

I am fairly new to Word Addin development. Fortunately I was able to do almost everything but stuck at some simple issue I belive.

I want to insert plain text controls dynamically at the selected range. For this I am using the following:

```
    currentDocument = application.ActiveDocument;
    foreach(var field in myFieldsList)
    {      
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = currentDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range;
         object oRng = rng;
         var contentControlPlain = application.ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlText, ref oRng);
         contentControlPlain.Tag = formField.FormFieldId.ToString();
         contentControlPlain.SetPlaceholderText(null, null, " <" + formField.FormFieldName + "> ");
         contentControlPlain.LockContentControl = (formField.TypeName.Trim() == "Blank");
    }
```

Code seems to be working fine but when I try to insert the second field it complains saying:

> **This method or property is not available because the current selection partially covers a plain text content control.**

I understand that addin is trying to insert next content control into the previously inserted plain text control. But I tried giving some other range and could not fix it. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: For now i fixed this by calling Range.InsertParagraphAfter() after adding each content control. But again i was intended to insert content controls in one single line but this way i insert one control in each line. :( Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding every content control use

```
Application.Selection.Start = lastControl.Range.End+1
```