# "Some Controls Could Not Be Added to This Location" When Adding More Than One Dropdown to a Cell in a Table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I am making a function in my access database that creates a calendar using a template with a pre-made table in it. It'll have a "status" dropdown for each shipment taking place on a given day. I was able to create a dropdown for each cell in the table, but as soon as I move the set statement inside of this do-while loop, I get the following message in word:

> Some controls could not be added to this location

followed by:

> Run-time error '4198': Command Failed

In access

I found this question mentioning problems with content controls:
[Adding content control throws an exception dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024481/adding-content-control-throws-an-exception-dynamically)

But it's not in VBA. Is it possible that there is some kind of equivalent issue here or is this a dead end?

```vb
For i = 1 + 1 To NUMBER_OF_WEEKS + 1 '16 + 1

        For j = 1 To NUMBER_OF_DAYS_IN_THE_WEEK ' 7

             Do While Not rst.EOF ' rst is a DAO.Recordset of shipping dates ordered chronologicly. multiple items can ship the same day
                If rst![Ship] <> currDay Then ' if nothing left to ship this day, move to next cell/row
                    Exit Do
                End If

                doc.Tables(1).Cell(i, j).Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf 'supposed to add a new line between dropdown lists

                Set DDown = doc.Tables(1).Cell(i, j).Range.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList) 'This line fails upon adding a second dropdown to a cell

                'Add items to dropdown
                DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "Shipping within 7 days"
                DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "On schedule"
                DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "On Hold"

            Loop

        'move to the next day
        currDay = currDay + 1
    Next j
Next i
```

I was expecting to result in multiple dropdown lists for each day, but it results in a single dropdown in the 2nd cell of the first row (can't ship on sundays so it skips the first cell of each row) before saying that the Content control cannot be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part about putting things in a table is making sure the target position is in the cell and not in the table structures or, in the case of content controls, within the content control. Working with `Range` objects makes this easier to control.

Note that it's not clear from the code in the question when `i` and `j` are being incremented, so the approach may need to be adjusted for the actual loops being performed. Since I don't have your database, my testing was done out-of-context, but something like this, building it into the code in the question.

First, declare objects for working with the target table, cell and range. The key is to collapse the target Range before inserting new content.

There's also an "oddity" when inserting numerous content controls in a loop that Word will suddenly mix up the actual target `Range` with that of the last content control inserted. For this reason, the code selects the target `Range` in each loop, which seems to help Word keep things straight...

```
Dim tbl As Word.Table, cel As Word.Cell
Dim celRange As Word.Range
Dim DDown As Word.ContentControl

Set tbl = doc.Tables(1) 'one table, so do it before the loop

Do While Not rst.EOF ' rst is a DAO.Recordset of shipping dates ordered chronologicly. multiple items can ship the same day
    If rst![Ship] <> currDay Then ' if nothing left to ship this day, move to next cell/row
        Exit Do
    End If

    Set cel =  tbl.Cell(i, j)
    Set celRange = cel.Range
    'Move the target focus to the end of the cell
    celRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    celRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1

    Set DDown = celRange.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList) 

    'Add items to dropdown
    DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "Shipping within 7 days"
    DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "On schedule"
    DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "On Hold"

    'The target range will still be ahead of the content control, so
    'Prepare for the next content control by adding a new paragraph
    ' and putting the target area at the end of the cell
    Set celRange = cel.Range
    celRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    celRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
    celRange.Text = vbCrLf  'add a new line between dropdown lists
    celRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

    'After some iterations, celRange remains attached to the inserted content control
    'causing an error about the target overlapping a plain text content control.
    'Selecting the range puts the focus for insertion in the right place
    celRange.Select
    Set DDown = Nothing

Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the current selection cursor position to a spot after the end of the control you just added. This is the solution offered in the SO question you reference in your question [Adding content control throws an exception dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024481/adding-content-control-throws-an-exception-dynamically)

The code in that question isn't VBA, but the underlying libraries are the same, hence the similarities.

Change your loop as follows:

```
    Do While Not rst.EOF ' rst is a DAO.Recordset of shipping dates ordered chronologicly. multiple items can ship the same day
        If rst![Ship] <> currDay Then ' if nothing left to ship this day, move to next cell/row
            Exit Do
        End If

        Set DDown = doc.Tables(1).Cell(i, j).Range.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList) 'This line fails upon adding a second dropdown to a cell

        ' move current selection to after the end of the newly added control
        doc.Application.Selection.Start = DDown.Range.End+1

        'Add items to dropdown
        DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "Shipping within 7 days"
        DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "On schedule"
        DDown.DropdownListEntries.Add "On Hold"

    Loop
```

Comment: It's still giving me the same errors. When I roll over the line of code you recommended, it said: `DDown.Range.End  = <The remote server machine does not exsist or is unavailable>`. is that a problem?